# AngularJS Firebase database ng-repeat filtered data into ngtable with ngTableParams

Tags: angularjs, arrays, firebase, angularjs-ng-repeat, firebase-realtime-database

I filter one Firebase database based on another and concatenate the result into one `$scope` and ng-repeat the $scope array `projectslist` in a ngtable with `ng-repeat="obj in projectslist"`, which works fine!
however, when I want to add `ngTableParams` to my table, it breaks and shows only the first object in the array.
 This time I ng-repeat like this: `ng-repeat="obj in $data"`.
here is the console log of the concatenated array:
[image]

here is the controller:

```
app.controller('ProjectCtrl', ["$scope", "$filter", "ngTableParams", "firebase", "Auth", "DatabaseRef", "$firebaseArray", "$firebaseObject",
    function ($scope, $filter, ngTableParams, firebase, Auth, DatabaseRef, $firebaseArray, $firebaseObject) {

        var userId = firebase.auth().currentUser.uid;

        $scope.projectslist = [];

        var projectsRef = DatabaseRef.ref('/users/' + userId).orderByKey().once("value")
            .then(function onSuccess(snapshot) {
                snapshot.child("projects").forEach(function (childSnapshot) {
                    var userprojects = childSnapshot.val();

                    var projectquery = DatabaseRef.ref("projects").orderByKey().equalTo(userprojects);
                    var list = $firebaseArray(projectquery);
                    $scope.list = $firebaseArray(projectquery);
                    list.$loaded(function(){
                        $scope.projectslist = $scope.projectslist.concat(list);

                    });
                    var data =  $scope.list;
                    data.$loaded().then(function(data) {
                        $scope.tableParams = new ngTableParams({
                            page: 1, // show first page
                            count: 7, // count per page
                        }, {
                            dataset: data,
                            filterSwitch: true,
                            getData: function ($defer, params) {
                                var filteredData = params.filter() ? $filter('filter')(data, params.filter()) :  data;
                                var orderedData = params.sorting() ? $filter('orderBy')(filteredData, params.orderBy()) : data;

                                params.total(data.length);
                                // set total for recalc pagination
                                $defer.resolve(orderedData.slice((params.page() - 1) * params.count(), params.page() * params.count()));

                            }
                        });
                    });
                });


            });    
}]);
```

### The question is:

how to ng-repeat the data in a table with ngTableParams working as well, filtering, sorting, pagination?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to first sort your data, then go for filtering and then you can apply pagination on the data.

```
$scope.tableParams = new NgTableParams(
                {
                    page : 1, // show first page
                    count : 5, // count per page
                },
                {
                    getData : function($defer, params) {
                        {
                            if (!$scope.projectslist|| !$scope.projectslist.length) { return; }
                            $scope.data = params.sorting() ? $filter('orderBy')($scope.projectslist, params.orderBy()) : $scope.projectslist;
                            $scope.data = params.filter() ? $filter('filter')($scope.data, params.filter()):$scope.data;
                            $scope.data = $scope.data.slice((params.page() - 1) * params.count(), params.page() * params.count());
                            $defer.resolve($scope.data);
                        }
                    }
                });
```

Then you can use it in html like below defined

```html
<table ng-table="tableParams" class="table table-striped responsive"  show-filter="true" border="1" cellspacing="1" style="padding-left: 100px;padding-right: 100px;">
       <tbody ng-repeat="obj in $data">
      <tr ng-form="rowForm">
    
       <td data-title="'Project Name'" filter="{'project_name':'text'}" sortable="'project_name'"
        style="overflow: auto; -webkit-overflow: auto;"
        ><label>{{obj.project_name}}</label>
       </td>
                          <!--<td>

  More rows </td>-->
</table>
```

Comment: working like a charm! how can I make a column binding, so that I choose which columns to show in the table using a checkbox? how is it possible?

Comment: you can use ng-hide attribute. Check https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngHide.